# Slide down the menu, but so it doesn't move everything else

Tags: jquery, html, css, interface, menu

All of my code works, but it does not work quite the way I want it. So, I would like to make a menu bar that when I hover over a part of it, it would make the options appear by sliding out from under the item, however, this does not push the other menu items down.

If you don't understand what I mean, you can copy the code if you like.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selector').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });
    $('.selector').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
body {
    width: 98%;
}
#title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 250%;
}
#menu_Bar {
    margin: 0.01%;
}
.sel_name {
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}
.empty {
    list-style: none;
}
.options {
    display: none;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.selector {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='title'>Welcome to My Site</h1>
    <div id='menu_Bar'>
        <div class='selector'>
            <p class='sel_name'>Home
                <p>
                    <ul style='display: none' class='empty'>
                        <li><a href=''>option 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 3</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 4</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 5</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='selector'>
            <p class='sel_name'>Shows
                <p>
                    <ul style='display: none' class='empty'>
                        <li><a href=''>option 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 3</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 4</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 5</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='selector'>
            <p class='sel_name'>Search
                <p>
                    <ul style='display: none' class='empty'>
                        <li><a href=''>option 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 3</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 4</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 5</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='selector'>
            <p class='sel_name'>About the Owner
                <p>
                    <ul style='display: none' class='empty'>
                        <li><a href=''>option 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 3</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 4</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 5</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='selector'>
            <p class='sel_name'>FAQ
                <p>
                    <ul style='display: none' class='empty'>
                        <li><a href=''>option 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 3</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 4</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=''>option 5</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a js fiddle and show us what's going on?

Comment: js fiddle? What is that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ a very handy tool! :) it allows you to put your code for other ls to see and run to see what is happening.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but if you have a menu that pushes down the content of your page for every hover, most users will experience a slow, jarring effect, especially on slower computers and older/IE browsers.

Comment: Add css :- .selector ul{position:'absolute';}
                     or
.empty{list-style: none; position:'absolute';}

Comment: whats it mean that i need a code to post links to js fiddle?

Comment: validate your `html`. Your `p` tags are not closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the CSS class `.selector`. I have added `float:left` and `display:block` instead of `inline-block`, making your content go with the hovered one.

Here is the updated code:

```css
.selector {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
}
```

[Find the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/XuBbU/2/)

Comment: Also why block, inline-block does the same

Comment: Hmm you r right...I am not that much in depth with CSS :(
but as I know 'inline-block' arranges content in a line , one after another. while the 'block' sets the content steady.
CSS guys can describe it right ways.

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` to the selector and use `position: absolute;`

I also fixed your typos.

[Here is my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/kYDyY/1/)